# 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 8-12: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, ascii

```
import smtplib
my_email = "redacted_email"
my_password = "redacted_password"
subject = "привет"

with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com") as connection:
    connection.starttls()
    connection.login(user=my_email,password=my_password)
    connection.sendmail(from_addr=my_email,to_addrs="insert recipient email here",
                       msg=f"Subject:{subject}")
```

I have tried the following:
subject = `u"\u0441\u043b\u0430\u0432\u0430\u0020\u0443\u043a\u0440\u0430\u0438\u043d\u0435".encode('utf-8')`

and

```
u"\u0441\u043b\u0430\u0432\u0430\u0020\u0443\u043a\u0440\u0430\u0438\u043d\u0435".encode('utf-8').decode('utf08')
```

but always end up with the same error.

Again, I am using python 3

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Both those lines work in Python3 (if you fix the typo in `utf08` in the second one).  Are you sure you are using Python3?  Python 2 does some implicit encoding to `ascii` in certain cases.  Post a [mcve]

Comment: `subject = "привет"`, then `msg=f"Subject:{subject}"` works fine for me using Python 3.

Comment: I tried fixing the typo and the subject I receive in my email for the first one is "b'\xd1\x81\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb0 \xd1\x83\xd0\xba\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb5'".     And if I try the second one I get the same error as in the title of my post.  Im using jupyterhub if that matters.

Comment: That implies you shouldn't be encoding it.

Comment: Encode the entire string you pass to the `msg` parameter, not only the interpolated `subject`.

Comment: Thank you all for your help, lenz's solution works.  Good day.